# Play-slick - Is default.db required?

Tags: database, scala, playframework-2.0, default, slick

I'm working on an application using Play and Slick. This app requires access to (at least) two databases and this is working fine when one is defined as default and other is named. Eg.,

```
db.default.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1"
db.db2.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.db2.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2"
```

I can then happily access each db as follows

```
DB.withSession { implicit session => ??? }   
DB("db2").withSession { implicit session => ??? }
```

However, this doesn't really make sense as there is no reason DB1 should be the default. The DBs contain different types of data, neither is the default, both are important. What I would like is:

```
db.db1.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.db1.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1"
db.db2.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.db2.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2"
```

Play-scala barfs at this thought. It needs a default db driver and URL and it needs to be able to connect to it.

Anyone know anyway to change this behaviour or to trick play into thinking it has a default?

**UPDATE**

To be clear, I've greped my code to ensure that I'm not using DB.withSession anywhere. That is, every time I create a session I use `DB("db1").withSession` or `DB("db2").withSession`. However, when I run my test, I still get an exception: 
`Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Slick error : jdbc driver not defined in application.conf for db.default.driver key]`

Something somewhere is trying to load the default config.

Comment: Sorry, this is a kind a motivator ;) reverted

Answer (score 0):

Default is just a name, with some convenience functions (withSession and withTransaction without name), so, **no** you do not need to have a default connection if it does not fit your project.

Comment: I've updated the issue to make it clear that this doesn't seem to be the case. With play-slick there is something, somewhere trying to load the default config.

Comment: Does the stack trace of the thrown error contain any info about what accessed Config.driver() ?

Comment: The driver is being accessed by MappedColumnType, but this is simply the first object to use the Play-slick DB. Looking at the debugger, the DB name is set to "db1" etc,. but it's still asking for default config. I'm going on leave for a three weeks, when I get back I'll recreate the issue using a vanilla play app and post the repo.